# Python Pandas - Compare rows in same dataset on different colomns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have this dataset:

DF1

```
| ID    | artshort  | artlong  |
| 248   | 123       |          |
| 249   | 456-1     |          |
| 100   | 456       | 456-1    |
```

As a result I want a dataset with the rows where artshort of one row is the same as artlong of another row.

I tried:

```
dftest = df1['artshort'].isin(df1['artlong'])]
```

But this is not working. Not sure if "isin" is the best approach in this case

Comment: You want `df1[df1['artshort'].isin(df1['artlong'])]]`?

Comment: Do you need a match with a **different** row? Can you explain **how** it doesn't work? Please give examples

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try filtering using this condition:

```py
data = {'ID': [248, 249, 100],
        'artshort': ['123', '456-1', '456'],
        'artlong': ['', '', '456-1']}

df1 = pd.DataFrame(data)

result = df1[df1['artshort'].isin(df1['artlong'])]
```

Output:

```
    ID  artshort    artlong
1   249 456-1
```